# Apache File Permissions only in /tmp

Tags: php, apache, file-permissions

I'm using CentOS 7 and PHP 7.2.5. I cannot get move_uploaded_file(), file_put_contents(), or exec('cp /tmp/test.txt /var/www/html/test.txt', $out); to work in any folder except /tmp. /var/www/html is owned by apache:apache and just for permissions are 755. I tried 777 and I still get permission denied. It was stuck in systemd-private-123abc-httpd.service-11cba/tmp/ folder, but I disabled PrivateTmp for httpd.

The uploaded file is uploaded and all is well until I try to move it. I can move it to another file name in the /tmp directory but I cannot move it to any other directory.

All these work fine:

```
file_put_contents('/tmp/test.txt', 'TTTTTEEEESSSSTTTTT!!!!');
exec('cp /tmp/test.txt /tmp/test2.txt', $out); 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], '/tmp/'.$file);
```

All these give Warning: ***: failed to open stream: Permission denied

```
file_put_contents('/var/www/html/test.txt', 'TTTTTEEEESSSSTTTTT!!!!');
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], '/var/www/html/'.$file);
exec('cp /tmp/test.txt /var/www/html/test2.txt', $out);
```

And again, /var/www/html is owned by apache:apache and set to 755 permissions. I am completely baffled. All this code worked fine on the old server but absolutely refuses to work on new server. I've looked and looked, but if the answer is out there, it's blocked by too many answers about standard file/directory permissions.

The exec('cp /... doesn't actually give warnings or errors. It works or does not work. It can copy within the /tmp directory but nowhere else.

Comment: Did you check if SELinux is enabled?

Comment: cOle2 - Yes, that was the problem. Details in answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above, SELinux was the problem. I disabled it and everything worked as expected. I didn't want to leave it off so I tried to set rules that would allow what I need, following [these directions](https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/web-servers-linux/configuring-selinux-policies-for-apache-web-servers/). That gave me errors "semanage: error: unrecognized arguments: /var/www/html/test.txt"

I ran semanage fcontext -l > output.txt and checked out the file. There was already a rule (for WordPress and/or Drupal) to allow read/write for any directory in /var/www/html named "uploads"
/var/www/html(/.*)?/uploads(/.*)?                  all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0

So, I moved my destination directory to a directory with "uploads" in the path.
mv -f /var/www/html/shared/pics/* /var/www/html/shared/uploads/pics

I chowned it all to apache:apache and set the permissions to 755 and it work as expected. So, if SELinux is giving you problems and you can't get the rules to change, find the rules and follow them.

Answer (score 0):

If you still in trouble try disable system privateTmp.

I've try "multi-user.target.wants" solution, it have worked but after restart, but at some point, PrivateTmp go back to true.
Like my principal use of Apache2 is PHP, I finally edited php.ini and I've uncomment line sys_temp_dir.

By default system use temp dir assigned by function sys_get_temp_dir. Function sys_get_temp_dir will return "/tmp" but the truth is that your tmp files are storing at some path like /tmp/systemd-private-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-apache2.service-YYYYYY//tmp/*. So, what work for me was:

Edit php.ini (path can change between PHP versions)

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
```

Then uncomment sys_temp_dir line

```
; Directory where the temporary files should be placed.
; Defaults to the system default (see sys_get_temp_dir)
sys_temp_dir = "/tmp"
```